# select nextAll including nth-child condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i select the nth-child plus the rest of div.containers i tried nextAll but that skips the nth-child

```
$('.container nth-child(' + index + ')').nextAll().each(function() {
    //problem here in selecting the next index ^^ plus the rest of div.container
});

<div>
    <div class="container" style="width:220px; height:220px; z-index:999; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:200px; height:200px; z-index:998; position:absolute; background-color:Blue; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:180px; height:180px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:160px; height:160px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Green; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you like to select at all, can you please explain which nodes you like to select for a specific given index

Comment: i just decreased the index by 1 then used next all so for now I think i've got thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the selector .andSelf() to the end before the each to include the original selector like this:

```
$('.container nth-child(' + index + ')').nextAll().andSelf().each(function()
```

that should do it for you. Here's the jQuery reference:  http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

Comment: is there a way to reverse the order going backwards in the each statement

Comment: The each function will do all of the elements in the selection. I guess I need more information. What do you intend to do with the elements in the each function? How does that relate to the order you seek to achieve? BTW, does andSelf put it first or last? Are they currently "eaching" in order?